# Execute PHP scraper script in cronjob

Tags: php, cron

I am trying to execute this script that will go fetch data from a site and import it into my database.

I have created the cronjob and waited for 20 minutes. There is no error or result, it is just silent like nothing happened.

I am also not getting an email showing the result of the command. How can I execute this script and also receive the result via email?

This is the cronjob I am currently using:

```
20  *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/GET http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/ScriptName/scrap_data2.php?request_type=import_animes&site=2
```

Comment: Is the url you have in the cronjob what is supposed to execute the script?  Or are you supposed to get data from that url and then do something with it?

Comment: @JoeP.   Thanks for the reply. Yes, that is the url executing the script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create cron job using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)

Comment: Are you not able to run the script directly from that server?  Or are you supposed to get data from that url and then do something with it?

Answer (score 0):

Although Hostgator does use GET as one of its cron examples; the usual way to "run" a script from cron via its http link is to use  "wget" or "curl".

I beleive "GET" is part of "libwww-perl" package and it may depend on where or whether this is installed. Try using WGET instead.

`20  *   *   *   *   wget -O /dev/null http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/ScriptName/scrap_data2`

'-O /dev/null' above is used to ditch cron wgets output as you won't need it since your script emails success.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it did not work. The script did not executed or send an email of command results.

Comment: just checked a working one of mine `40 1 * * * nice -n15 wget -O /dev/null --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1" "http://example.com/somedir/some-script.php"` the "script link" is in quotes and I've added a user agent (some servers may require them?).  nice -n15 is probably irrelevant it just makes script run at low resource priority. Other than try CURL nothing else to suggest if this example does not help.

Comment: I did this `/usr/bin/wget -O -q 'https://your_site_url.com/wp-content/plugins/scriptname/scrap_data.php?request_type=import_animes&site=1'` and it worked.